# Blocked event loop when resolving promise with a lot of data

Tags: node.js, promise, blocking, event-loop

I'm running NodeJS in a kubernetes environment and don't won't my application to be killed/restarted by kubernetes because of not answered liveness probes. E.g. I have to make sure the event loop is not blocked.

In particular I'm parsing (sometimes huge) CSV files using [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse). I'm streaming data from Minio and parsing it line by line using the PapaParse `step` function. No problem until here.

In the end the parsed data is returned using `resolve`. When this is done the event loop is blocked depending on the size of the returned data. And I don't understand why.

```
const parseCSVfromMinio = async (filename) => {
  const data = await minioClient.getObject(
    process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    filename,
  );

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const result = { meta: {}, data: [] };

    papaParse.parse(data, {
      complete: () => {
        resolve(result);
      },

      error: (err) => {
        reject(err);
      },

      step: (results) => {
        // gets CSV data row by row
        result.data.push(results.data);
        result.meta = results.meta;
      },
    });
  });
};
```

EDIT: Seems like `blocked-at` lead me to wrong assumptions. When using static data and no `async` the blockage shifted to another (more reasonable) part of the code.

Comment: If the library doesn’t provide any means of parsing CSV asynchronously, you should look into reading and parsing the source line-by-line as a stream. This will throttle the parsing and allow Kubernetes’ health check calls to be answered quickly.

Comment: You should not use `getObject`, papaParase and other libraries support readable streams. You want to pipe the minio/s3 file as a readable stream into papaparse and pipe the output of that somewhere else so nothing ever parses the whole file or is in memory.

Comment: I totally agree to use streams. In this particular case I need to verify the whole data before going on. I have no problem while parsing the data but when resolving. If I write a `console.log('Finished');` before the `resolve()` I can see it and then the event loop is blocked for a few seconds. Why does this happen is my main question. @BenjaminGruenbaum can you elaborate on why `getObject` does not return as stream (as mentioned in the docs)?